# jQuery Updating records from DataTables plug-in into a database

Tags: c#, jquery, database, web-services, datatables

I would like to know what's the best way to insert records from Datatables into a database, just noticing that I'm using ASP.NET/WebForms & WebServices to retrieve the information from DB.

Comment: Know what is possible?  Best way to do what?  What exactly is the DataTables plugin?  (Provide link)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most people using DataTables are using MVC.  However, here is a step-by-step tutorial on how to use it with WebForms:

Part 1:  http://blueorbitsoftware.com/blog/?p=17

Part 2:  http://blueorbitsoftware.com/blog/?p=78